# Haskel, GUI Libraries

Tags: user-interface, haskell

I am implementing the Mandelbrot-set in Haskell. I am want to create zoomable version of the mandeblrot set hence I want to create a GUI application where mandelbrot image takes all the screen and **the user can draw a rectangle on the screen by holding down the mouse and dragging to create a rectangle** the area under the rectangle will then be zoomed in.

I have manged to create mandelbrot computation functions in Haskell, However I am having trouble finding a library that allows me to generate an image and implenent the interactive zooming functionality that I want.

Do you have any suggestions of what GUI\Graphics Library I should be using? Ideally the library should be well documented with samples as i am an amature in functional programming

Comment: There are almost 500 packages in the [graphics section of Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Graphics).

Comment: You can certainly do this with gtk2hs alone, in fact I daresay this is overall going to be easiest (because it's so fully featured and well-supported). As far as examples go, I'd reckommend my [dynamic-plot library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dynamic-plot-0.1.2.0/docs/Graphics-Dynamic-Plot-R2.html), which actually focuses on exactly this kind of task (but I haven't used it for anything fractal yet).

Comment: @DanielWagner That's what makes this a good question.

Comment: @PyRulez: *"Do you have any suggestions of what GUI\Graphics Libarary I should be using?"* makes it an off-topic question, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Zeta You can take a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4edxwz/zoomable_gui_library/

Comment: @PyRulez I think you've missed my point. Daniel's comment exactly states why this question ___isn't___ a good one (for StackOverflow). Also, I've already commented on the reddit topic three hours ago.

Comment: @Zeta Oh wait, I thought you where the OP asking that question to me (and didn't see the second half of the comment). Sorry.

Comment: @PyRulez No problem. Was just slightly confused. (I usually put quotes in italics in comments, since `> blockquote` syntax doesn't work :/).